# Fix spacing between items in multi-carousel

Tags: css, reactjs, react-multi-carousel

I'm trying to use the react-multi-carousel library to construct a responsive carousel with fixed size items. I want to fix the spacing between the items as well. However, with react-multi-carousel, the space between items depends on the number of items to be displayed (specified in "responsive"). Is there a way to make the carousel responsive with the *space* between the elements being the input rather than number of elements? i.e I want to show fixed size elements with 32 px space between them on 1024 devices(16 px in smaller device) and don't care how many items are displayed.

```
import Carousel from "react-multi-carousel";
import "react-multi-carousel/lib/styles.css";
const responsive = {
  superLargeDesktop: {
    // the naming can be any, depends on you.
    breakpoint: { max: 4000, min: 3000 },
    items: 5
  },
  desktop: {
    breakpoint: { max: 3000, min: 1024 },
    items: 3
  },
  tablet: {
    breakpoint: { max: 1024, min: 464 },
    items: 2
  },
  mobile: {
    breakpoint: { max: 464, min: 0 },
    items: 1
  }
};
<Carousel responsive={responsive}>
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
  <div>Item 4</div>
</Carousel>;
```

The problem with this approach is the space between 2 items becomes very large and looks strange. I would rather fix the space and adjust the items based on that. One workaround I thought of doing was calculating the number of items based on the screen width whenever the window resizes. i.e

```
    breakpoint: { max: 4000, min: 3000 },
    items: window.innerWidth/WidthOfItemPlusMargin
```

I have to listen to window resize events for this. Is there a better way?

Comment: Provide some code.

Comment: @flvps Just did

Comment: Hey buddy! 
Did you try to use <Carousel itemClass="carousel-item-padding-0-px"> ... </Carousel> ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a class for your item

```
.carouselItem{
    padding-right: 40px
}
```

Add 2 props to Carousel

1. Use `itemClass` to use your class
2. Add `partialVisible={false}` for the carousel to fix itself whenever your items are being cut from view

```
<Carousel itemClass={styles.carouselItem} partialVisible={false}>
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
  <div>Item 4</div>
</Carousel>
```